# filter not work properly with group by in angular js

Tags: angularjs

When i have search with comedy then its also give the result while we want
filter only with title not with category. so count and result will be wrong.
can any body suggest me how can we develop the custom filter with group by or have any other way on same.

my Code is

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);

myApp.controller("MyController", function ($scope) 
{
    $scope.movies = 
    [
        { title: 'The Matrix', rating: 7.5, category: 'Action' },
        { title: 'Focus', rating: 6.9, category: 'Comedy' },
        { title: 'The Lazarus Effect', rating: 6.4, category: 'Thriller' },
        { title: 'Everly', rating: 5.0, category: 'Action' },
        { title: 'Maps to the Stars', rating: 7.5, category: 'Drama' }
    ];
});     

</script>
<div ng-controller="MyController"> 
    <div class="searchBar">
        <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
    <ul class="angularList" ng-repeat="(key, value) in movies  | groupBy: 'category'">
        <h3>{{ key }} ({{ value.length }})</h3>
        <li ng-repeat="movie in value | filter:title">
            <a href="#">{{ movie.title }}</a><br />
            <div class="rating_box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:{{movie.rating*10}}%"></div>
            </div>
        </li>               
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use something like this to apply filter on title only ng-repeat="(key, value) in movies | filter:{ title: title}

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you please explain, with an example, what you're doing, what you expect to happen (with example desired output) and what actually happens (with example actual output)?

Comment: are you added **angular filter.js** [Just go Through once](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

Comment: J-D, it will ignore all the category, while category will be display with count 0

Comment: JB Nizet, Please see --- When user enters string to search:
 the list is filtered, and only movies which title contains the search string are shown.
Categories remain visible, but count changes to account for the number of movies that are shown for the category.
Movies are grouped within categories according to the “category” attribute.

Answer (score 0):

the solution found on: [Solution](http://sobrepere.com/blog/2014/10/14/creating-groupby-filter-angularjs/)
    You'r script:

```
    myApp.filter('groupBy', function ($timeout) {
    return function (data, key) {
        if (!key) return data;
        var outputPropertyName = '__groupBy__' + key;
        if(!data[outputPropertyName]){
            var result = {};  
            for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                if (!result[data[i][key]])
                    result[data[i][key]]=[];
                result[data[i][key]].push(data[i]);
            }
            Object.defineProperty(data, outputPropertyName, {enumerable:false, configurable:true, writable: false, value:result});
            $timeout(function(){delete data[outputPropertyName];},0,false);
        }
        return data[outputPropertyName];
    };
})
```

In your HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl"> 
    <div class="searchBar">
        <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
    <ul class="angularList" ng-repeat="(key, value) in (myCtrl.movies  | groupBy: 'myCtrl.category')">
        <h3>{{ key }} ({{ value.length }})</h3>
        <li ng-repeat="movie in value | filter:title">
            <a href="#">{{ movie.title }}</a><br />
            <div class="rating_box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:{{movie.rating*10}}%"></div>
            </div>
        </li>               
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it's working fine for me. Please check this URL https://jsbin.com/tapeke/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yes, its working fine, but here we want to filter only with title not for "rating and category"

Answer (score 0):

i have also tested your code it's working fine...
below code is working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MainController"> 

    <div class="searchBar">
        <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
    <ul class="angularList" ng-repeat="(key, value) in movies  | groupBy: 'category'">
        <h3>{{ key}} ({{ value.length}})</h3>
        <li ng-repeat="movie in value| filter:title">
            <a href="#">{{ movie.title}}</a><br />
            <div class="rating_box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:{{movie.rating * 10}}%"></div>
            </div>
        </li>               
    </ul>

</div>
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter'])

            .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
                $scope.movies =
                        [
                            {title: 'The Matrix', rating: 7.5, category: 'Action'},
                            {title: 'Focus', rating: 6.9, category: 'Comedy'},
                            {title: 'The Lazarus Effect', rating: 6.4, category: 'Thriller'},
                            {title: 'Everly', rating: 5.0, category: 'Action'},
                            {title: 'Maps to the Stars', rating: 7.5, category: 'Drama'}
                        ];
            });


</script>
```